# RGBD SLAM GUI not displaying any video feed

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using ROS Diamondback on Ubuntu 10.04 running on VMware Player. I have also connected a Kinect camera via USB. I think I have installed all required drivers and build all the necessary files without failures.

However, when I execute this command:

roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch

The RGBDSLAM GUI opens up, but it doesn't display any video. Two windows in the bottom say "Waiting for monochrome image..." and "Waiting for depth image..."

When I press space and stop, I see that 0 bytes of data has been recorded. The same thing happens when I press enter to get a single frame.

I am sort of stuck at a dead end, and really have no clue where things are going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35628/rgbd-slam-gui-not-displaying-any-video-feed/) by [periphery](https://answers.ros.org/users/2488/periphery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems there are problems with vmware, see [this question and its answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/12708/rgbdslam-installation-problem/)

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0